# Spring mvc,java.lang.NullPointerException while adding an item in a set of an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, set

I have two entities "billable" and item. There is bidirectional oneToMany mapping between both.
When I am trying to add set of item to billable. It is showing:

> "java.lang.NullPointerException"

How can I add set of item to billable properly.
I am trying to add item to billable like this. Another entity user has set of items also.

```
 Set<Item> s = (Set)user.getItem();
 for(Item i:s){
     Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();

     System.out.println(i.getItemName());
     Item myItem = (Item)i;

     bill.getItem().add(myItem);
 }
```

Here is my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/checkOut",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String checkOut(@RequestParam("id")String userName){

     billable bill = new billable();
     bill.setBillableName(rName);
     bill.setBillableAddress(bAddress);

     User user = userService.getuserByName(userName);

     bill.setUser(user);

     Set<Item> s = (Set)user.getItem();

     for(Item i:s){
         Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();

         System.out.println(i.getItemName());
         Item myItem = (Item)i;

         bill.getItem().add(myItem);
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your Billable object has a field like:
    private Set item;

There are two options here:

Option 1, in your Billable object, on the getItem() method, add a null check:

```
public Set<Item> getItem() {
    if (item == null) {
        item = new HashSet<>();
    }
    return item;
 }
```

This is a fairly common approach.

Option two, change your controller you set the items, not the item:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/checkOut",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String checkOut(@RequestParam("id")String userName){

 billable bill = new billable();
 bill.setBillableName(rName);
 bill.setBillableAddress(bAddress);

 User user = userService.getuserByName(userName);

 bill.setUser(user);

 Set<Item> s = (Set)user.getItem();

 Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();
 for(Item i:s){

     System.out.println(i.getItemName());
     Item myItem = (Item)i;
     //I'm assuming your gonna actually do something here, not just loop for fun
     items.add(i);
 }
 bill.setItem(items);
```